# Tensorboard: All experiments were written as one (without provided tags)

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard, torch

I wanted to compare several runs that I did in the loop creating new SummaryWriter instances like this:

```
for experiment_name in experiments:
    logger = SummaryWriter(self._log_path, comment=experiment_name)
    ...
    for epoch in range(5):
        ...
        logger.add_scalar("Epoch Loss", loss, epoch)
        ...
    logger.close()
```

In the log path I got several files like this:

```
events.out.tfevents.1609675249.nlp-vm.13735.0
events.out.tfevents.1609679736.nlp-vm.13735.1
events.out.tfevents.1609687200.nlp-vm.13735.2
events.out.tfevents.1609691662.nlp-vm.13735.3
events.out.tfevents.1609699158.nlp-vm.13735.4
events.out.tfevents.1609703743.nlp-vm.13735.5
events.out.tfevents.1609711308.nlp-vm.13735.6
events.out.tfevents.1609716054.nlp-vm.13735.7
```

But the Tensorboard displays all runs as one:

1. [example](https://discuss.pytorch.org/uploads/default/original/3X/d/3/d30e6592ab54112925928c1015c77d6f3c298f07.png)
2. [example](https://discuss.pytorch.org/uploads/default/original/3X/b/a/ba52cc1348a958c459ff48544369db3410b9afa8.png)

Could you say what I should do to fix it and can I do it without re-running all experiments?

Answer (score 1):

The events files that I have in the one folder should be in the separate and the folder name will be displayed as an experiment name.

Also found the important note in the [`SummaryWriter` documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html#torch.utils.tensorboard.writer.SummaryWriter.__init__):

- **comment** (*string*): Comment log_dir suffix appended to the default
  `log_dir`. If `log_dir` is assigned, this argument has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate the experiment name when logging a new data point. Something like:

```
logger.add_scalar('%s Epoch Loss' % experiment_name, loss, epoch)
```

Comment: Could work, but in this way, I would not be able to compare runs. I found the solution, will write it in the new comment)